# React find DOM node by refs set to variable?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, meteor-react

I am dynamically creating multiple text inputs (with dynamically created refs) along side the text that I want updated with the input.

I am trying to get the value of the input by setting the ref to a variable and finding the DOM node with React.findDOMNode(this.refs.Variable).value

I am getting a "Cannot read property 'value' of null" error.

How can I achieve this?

This is what the function looks like:

```
resetUnit: function(e){
  var refID = e.target.id;
  var ID = refID.split("-")[0];
  var Value = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.refID).value;
  NodesCollection.update({_id: ID},{$set: { materialUnit : Value}});
  this.setState({
    edit: ''
  });
},
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var Value = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.refID).value;
```

finds the DOM node for the component with the ref `"refID"`. If you want to find the DOM node for the component with the ref `refID` (the variable), you need

```
var Value = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs[refID]).value;
```

Comment: I guess it would be `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` not `React.findDOMNode`

Comment: anybody having problems with this as in June 2019? This doesn't seem to be working for me

Answer (score 2):

I had to do

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.hi);
```

in React 15.2.1 (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.finddomnode)

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting a "Cannot read property 'value' of null" error.

Two possible cases:

- the id is wrong. Review further code or `log` to double check the ID is what you think it is
- Called to early: Are you sure that `componentDidMount` has been called?

Comment: The ID is correct, and meteor (I think) handles the componentDidMount. The issue is in trying to find "this.refs" with a variable.

Comment: For example: var A = foo;  React.findDOMNode(this.refs.A).value;